# sorting class array java

Tags: java, sorting

I have made a class as follows:

```
class strVal{
    double val;
    String str;
}
```

Now I made an array of this class now I want to sort that array by `strVal.val`. I want to know if there is any standard defined method in Java?

Comment: Consider using a `List` (`ArrayList`) instead, and then [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Comment: As pointed out by The New Idiot, you should adhere to Java naming conventions. For instance, strVal should be StrVal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Implement java.lang.Comparable interface, and use java.util.Arrays.sort(...) to sort an array of StrVal:

```
public class StrVal implements Comparable<StrVal> {

  private double val;
  private String str;

  public StrVal(double val, String str) {
    this.val = val;
    this.str = str;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(StrVal o) {
    return (int)(this.val - o.val);
  }

  public double getVal() {
    return val;
  }

  public String getStr() {
    return str;
  }
}
```

To sort the array :

```
StrVal[] array;

...

Arrays.sort(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

Collections.sort might help you. Use a `List<strVal>` and then:

```
Collections.sort(list, comparator);
```

Some more code:

```
List<strVal> list = ...;
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<strVal>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(strVal o1, strVal o2)
                            {
                                return o1.val - o2.val;
                            }
                        });
```

Or if you don't want to use a List, use `Arrays.sort(array, comparator)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) or [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and then call [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) on the collection of obejects of your class strVal.  Follow this tutorial for learning more about collections sorting:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: I want to return double value from compareTo() function but is not accepting double. I did this as followsclass strVal implements Comparable<strVal>{
   double val;
   String str;
   @Override
   public double compareTo(strVal another) {
    double first = another.val; 
     
    //ascending order
    return first - this.val;
   }
  }

Comment: @navalp3 If you are implementing the compareTo method then you need to follow the signature defined in Comparable interface, otherwise Collections.sort will not work. CompareTo() Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

Answer (score 0):

*now I made an **array** of this class now I want to sort that array by strVal.val.*

You can implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), override its [compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,T%29) method and use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,java.util.Comparator%29).

In case you use a `List<strVal>` use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,java.util.Comparator%29).

If you think that the comparison of the class objects can be done only by its `val` property and that property defines the natural ordering of the objects then your class can implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

**Comparator :**

```
new Comparator<strVal>()
{
     @Override
     public int compare(strVal o1, strVal o2)
     {
          return o1.val - o2.val;
     }
});
```

**Comparable:**

```
class strVal implements Comparable<strVal>{
    double val;
    String str;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(strVal o) {
         return this.val - o.val;
    }   
}
```

**P.s.:** Please adhere to Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement the comparable interface for that and make your val field the field where the compare will take place.

More info here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)-interface and use the sort methods of the collection

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `sort` method defined in the [`Arrays` utility class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

In order to sort according to your key you should either make your class implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or provide a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).